# bootstrap get ids from tagsinput

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have library tagsinput and i want to return ids of the tags (added by the user). In window.acNodes.ttAdapter is array which has id and value but in input there is only value.. How can i get the ids?

```
elt.tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'value',
        itemText: 'value',
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'value',
            displayKey: 'value',
            templates: {
            empty: [
              '<p>Could not find this word.</p>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> <div style='font-size:12px;'>#{{id}} {{author_name}}</div></p>")
        },
        source: window.acNodes.ttAdapter()
  }     
});
```

tagsinput has method items() but nothing returning how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add in the typeaheadjs config:

```
...
valueKey: 'id',
...
```

Then you will get values with

```
elt.tagsinput('items')
```